# Problems when I call a bash script from C with system()

Tags: c, bash, makefile, system-calls

I have a client - server application written in *C*. It's a basic application where client does an update request to server. If there are updates available, an archive file is sent to client. Further, the client unpack it, and run a specific *bash* script from that unpacked archive. That's the summary. I'll present bellow the *C* function that does the update on the client side:

```
void executeUpdates(char *path) {

    char    command[100];
    char    *tmp;

    strcpy(command, "tar xzf ");
    tmp = mystrcat(command, path);
    mystrcat(tmp, " -C /netnfork/updates/");
    system(command); //up to this point, I created the extract command and executed it.
    command[0] = '\0';
    path[strlen(path) - 7] = '\0';
    strcpy(command, path);
    strcat(command, "/update.sh");
    system(command);// up to this point, I created the command to run the update script and ran it.

}
```

The problem is as follows:

**Problem:** In the first updates when I put in `update.sh` script some simple commands (by simple I mean a few), it works well. When I put in this script some commands that do archive extraction, compilation with `./configure`, `make`, `make install`, the script hangs in a specific point forever.

Specifically, in the update archive, I have six *tar.bz* archives that I need to extract and install. It works well for first 5 archives, but when script arrive to the point of the sixth *tar.bz* installation, it hangs on. If I run this script directly from terminal, it runs well, without any problem.

**Question**: Do anyone have some thoughts on solving this issue?

N.B. If you need more specific details or the script content, just tell me.

N.B1. I run the update *C* program as root.

Comment: For the 6th tarball, when you run the configure, make, make install, does it ask you questions interactively by any chance? if so, then it's just waiting on a read of stdinput. If you have options to run your configure, make, make install in non interactive mode, try it.

Comment: @rectummelancolique No, this is not the case.

Comment: What is `path`? you are using it twice, once as an archive, once as a folder path. `tar xzf PATH -C /netnfork/updates/` and `PATH/update.sh`. Try changing the last one to `system("/netnfork/updates/update.sh")`

Comment: @SergeyL. This is not the problem. The `path` is `/netnfork/updates` in this case. As I already mentioned, the script runs from update application, so I doubt there would be this kind of problems.

Comment: What command is make running when it hangs (what command has make printed just before it hung)?  You can also use `ps` or `pstree` to find out what processes are running.  Once you figure out which one is stopped, you can use something like `strace -p <pid>` to see what it's waiting for.  Most likely it's waiting for some kind of input.  You can try adding `</dev/null` to avoid that hang.

Comment: @MadScientist Can the output stream size of the update program constitute a problem. I mean the buffer is overwhelmed?

Comment: Not a problem for make, for sure.  This would only be a problem if whatever was reading the output stopped reading it for some reason.  It's not possible to overwhelm `/dev/null` so if you redirected output there it won't be a problem, unless you're running a pipeline and some process internal to the pipeline is stopped.  Without knowing what commands are hanging there's little else we can say.  See my previous comment for how to perform further debugging.

Comment: @MadScientist Your suggestion (redirect output to `/dev/null`) solved the problem. You can put it as answer to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your bash script runs fine up to some point and then something fails. Probably some process shows an error message but you don't read it because you don't inspect stderr. You should modify the script to write stdout and stderr of the failing step into e.g. /tmp/$$.err for debugging.

Comment: The process didn't fails. It hangs on. Specifically, it executes `./configure` and in `make`, somwhere in the middle, it hangs on. I can't say it fails.

Comment: but still there might be a hint in its stderr and it's so easy: just append `>/tmp/1.out 2>/tmp.1.err` to the command. this is not windows where you get a useless message.

Comment: I did it before to write this question. No hints.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why user829755's answer didn't work for you since you said redirecting output solved the problem: maybe you meant redirecting the input from `/dev/null` solved the problem?

If something is trying to read from stdin the `</dev/null` will typically fix that.

Comment: that's funny. he asked you to put your comment as an answer and when you do it he accepts my answer. thanks anyway